# What is the purpose of Yogi and Aghoris life?

Tags: history, belief, moksha, superstitions, yogi

Heard that they are supreme saints who are meditating to save the earth. But border clashes always persist. Covid could not be controlled nor avoided to enter India. 12 years of Kumba mela has lead more cases in India because of them.

Are they self centred to attain Moksha, do they really wanted to be Saints? or they just avoided normal life to escape from daily responsibilities is the question always taunts me?

Please enlighten me with strong ethical points here.

Comment: What is 'Normal life' ? I always like this quote: "There is no diffrence between Ordinary and Abnormal. They are one and the same for some or the other."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problems like Corona are natural phenomenon and there is no need to bring in Saints to solve it. Everyone faces their own individual Karma. Scriptures say that the world is a very dangerous place to live in and so advice moksha. Saints understand and share pain of others and try to uplift them from Avidya by bestowing Jnana which gives strength to face all problems with hope and transcend them.

> It is said that **great personalities almost always accept voluntary
> suffering because of the suffering of people in general**. This is
> considered the highest method of worshiping the Supreme Personality of
> Godhead, who is present in everyone’s heart.(Bhagavata 8.7.44)
>
> I regard them to be perfect yogis who see the true equality of all
> living beings and **respond to the joys and sorrows of others as if
> they were their own**.(BG 6.32)
>
> **Learn the Truth by approaching a spiritual master**. Inquire from him with reverence and render service unto him. Such an **enlightened
> Saint can impart knowledge unto you** because he has seen the
> Truth.(BG 4.34)
>
> One who knows the transcendental nature of My appearance and
> activities does not, upon leaving the body, take his birth again in
> this material world, but attains My eternal abode, O Arjuna.(BG 4.9)
>
> After attaining Me, the great souls, who are yogi’s in devotion, never
> return to this **temporary world, which is full of miseries**, because
> they have attained the highest perfection.(BG 8.15)

Comment: So according to this theory, saints/yogis only help/guide only if one becomes follower? Not for all? Though they know truth, they dont reveal the information. They will try their best to attain moksha in deed. So are they self centred here?

Comment: Saints are for the welfare of the whole world. See welfare activities for Eg Ramakrishna Matha performs. They perform to everyone even if majority guys dont even join there. Who said they wont reveal information? They teach to everyone. How are Saints self centered when they are experiencing pains and sharing joys and sufferings of others and helping everyone transcend this body feeling? @Hansiemithun

Comment: I understand @Sethu Srivatsa Koduru, you are being diplomatic and consoling the statements. Even i know what ever you are saying above, but the dimension of my doubts are little above and beyond. We are witnessing so many deaths today and none of the saints have made something useful so far. I dont believe in the astrologers who come in the media. Atleast these people should have done to safeguard this place as this is Ram Janam Bhoomi. I can myself console any person who come to me and ill also uplift them at my best even without being saint and thus does many. The point was different here...

Comment: Saints are not paid job, and i also know even if someone come front and give reason, today people will not take it seriously and ignore and hence they wont come. So, if i or anybody wants to know what is the reason behind this, how can we realise this? Is this a biological war or was that due to the brutality of humans against nature and animals/ What exactly?

Comment: I have no reason to be diplomatic. Birth Death Dieases like HIV Cholera Corona all these have nothing to do with Saints or so called God. Its because of Humans( We know which country is reason for this ) and their stupid innovations that these things come. Who asked you to believe in Astrology? Vedanta has nothing to do with Astrology. What is your point? Be straight, Dont beat round the bush. Who knows if its biological war or not? What this has to be with saints? Ramakrishna Matha is doing a lot in this time. Nursing sick, providing free food clothes and many other things @Hansiemithun

Comment: HIV, cholera are not contagious. This is corona like plague... Such questions are coming out of curiosity and frustration also when we lose close and dear ones ..

Comment: What do saints have to do with your frustration and these diseases? @Hansiemithun

Comment: There are saints whom i believe has super natural powers, but its not working today for all